NPM Command Not Recognized Despite Installation-'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe""C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-prefix.js"'
I’m encountering an issue with npm on my Windows machine. When I run npm --version in the command line, I get the following output:
C:\\Users\\nares\>npm --version
'CALL "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-prefix.js"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
10.8.2

I've tried:

Reinstalling Node.js and npm multiple times.
Checking the PATH environment variable to ensure it includes the paths to Node.js and npm.
Running the command prompt as an administrator.
Clearing the npm cache with npm cache clean --force

Has anyone encountered this issue before?

Can you give more information, for example npm & node versions. And can you compare your npm-prefix.js file with on this code:
// npm-prefix.js
#!/usr/bin/env node
// This is a single-use bin to help windows discover the proper prefix for npm
// without having to load all of npm first
// It does not accept argv params

const path = require('path')
const Config = require('@npmcli/config')
const { definitions, flatten, shorthands } = require('@npmcli/config/lib/definitions')
const config = new Config({
  npmPath: path.dirname(__dirname),
  // argv is explicitly not looked at since prefix is not something that can be changed via argv
  argv: [],
  definitions,
  flatten,
  shorthands,
  excludeNpmCwd: false,
})

async function main () {
  try {
    await config.load()
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(config.globalPrefix)
  } catch (err) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.error(err)
    process.exit(1)
  }
}
main()

